# Why does protobuf miss some params when equals to 0 in python?

Tags: python-3.x, protocol-buffers

### I expect that there is no missing value when i serialize and parse, but protoc version 3.9.2 have a problem.

the protofile is show below:

```
syntax = "proto3";
package example;
message person {
    int32 id = 1;
    string name = 2;
}
message all_person {
    repeated person Per = 1;
}
```

when i set id=0, name='hello' , i expect to show the "id": 0, 
but after SerializeToString and parseToString, it returns

```
{
  "Per": [
    {
      "name": "hello"
    }
  ]
}
```

but if i set id=1,name='hello', it returns

```
{
  "Per": [
    {
      "id": 1,
      "name": "hello"
    }
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Zero is the *default* value for numerics (similarly, strings default to empty, booleans to false). See [here](https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/docs/proto#optional) for more details.

For efficiency, Protobuf relies on these default value. In our system (using FastRTPS and Protobuf for pub/sub), default values are not transmitted across the wire. Based on what you're seeing, it doesn't worry about them for serialisation either.

However, this is only the *default* behaviour and may be changeable. For example, if you're using [`MessageToJson`](https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/docs/reference/python/google.protobuf.json_format-module.html#MessageToJson), you can simply set an optional parameter `including_default_value_fields` to `True`, stating you want the defaults output as well:

```
jsonStr = MessageToJson(myMsg, True)
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but if i really want to get the default value, i need to get the value of every params, what should i do? i have modify the has_default_value, default_value, but it doesn't work

Comment: Thank you again ,i solve my problem!!!  i can parse the pbstring by setting including_default_value_fields=True, and then dealing the data..